# IE8 doesn't display embedded web fonts -- on any site

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, webfonts, embedded-fonts

From what I understand, IE 8 should display embedded fonts, however my version substitutes generic fonts -- not just for my code, but on other sites, even when the CSS is properly IE-hacked (for example, [this sample](http://www.alistapart.com/d/css3-bling-in-the-real-world/examples/blingv2.html) displays all the IE-hacked properties for me (shadows, etc.), except for the embedded font).

I'm wondering if there is a setting in IE8 that would cause this? I'm on a heavily locked-down work computer (this is why I'm using IE8), so that may have something to do with it, though I'm not sure why this would affect font-face specifically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Universal problem, it's happening on all sites with embedded web fonts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533034(v=vs.85).aspx

- On the View menu, click Options and then click the Security tab.
- Select Custom and click Settings.
- Scroll to the Downloads section.
- Change the Font Download setting from Disable to Enable.

Comment: I guess that would be under Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom Level in IE8? Sadly I can't access that, was hoping for a workaround. Thank you though :)

Comment: @Nails, yes, it’s the. The factory settings allow font downloading, so someone has (probably intentionally) changed the setting. Thus, you need to contact your boss or IT department and tell them why you need to have setting changed.